# IF Statement condition

Tags: java

This is my code, and i have a simple question

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import type.lib.GlobalCredit;
import type.lib.CreditCard;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;


public class eCheck08A

{
public static void main(String[] args)

{
    PrintStream out = System.out;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    GlobalCredit credit1 = new GlobalCredit().getRandom();

    out.print("Enter report range in years ... ");
    int range = in.nextInt();
    out.println("Cards expiring before " + range + " year(s) from now: ");

    SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    for (CreditCard cc : credit1)
    {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(cc.getExpiryDate());
    c.add(Calendar.YEAR, range);
    Date newDate = c.getTime();

        if (cc.getExpiryDate().compareTo(newDate) < range)
        {
            if(cc.getExpiryDate().compareTo(newDate) > range)
            {
                out.print("*");
            }
            out.print(cc.getNumber());
            out.println("\t" + sf.format(cc.getExpiryDate()));

        }
    }



}
}
```

output of what it should look like:

```
Enter report range in years ... 3
Cards expiring before 3 years from now:

561561-8 20/11/2015
045645-7 22/02/2017
456462-3 16/04/2013 *
546548-5 19/08/2016
```

The current year is 2012
The person enters '3' as range.
so any year that is from 2012-2015 should have a " * ". Like the output above, 2013 has a " * ".
Can you tell what i am doing wrong in my IF statement?

Comment: Check the javadocs for [`Date.compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29), it's not guaranteed to be > or < than the value of range, just > or < 0

Comment: I am *sooo* adding the [tag:homework] tag...

Comment: Didn't we have question similar to this already a few days ago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comparing `cc.getExpiryDate()` with the **current date + the range**, you want the `newDate` to be:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
// commenting this line out because getInstance() gives us the current date already
//    c.setTime(cc.getExpiryDate());
c.add(Calendar.YEAR, range);
Date newDate = c.getTime();
```

This `newDate` is "range" years ahead of the current date. Now you can start comparing your `cc.getExpiryDate()` values:

```
    // expiry date is BEFORE the date + "range" years ahead
    if (cc.getExpiryDate().compareTo(newDate) < 0)
    {
        // the expiry date is AFTER or ON the current date
        if(cc.getExpiryDate().compareTo(new Date()) >= 0)
        {
            out.print("*");
        }
    }
    out.print(cc.getNumber());
    out.println("\t" + sf.format(cc.getExpiryDate()));
```

Answer (score 1):

The compareTo method does not return what you expect. It is only guaranteed to return a negative if the first argument is less, positive if it is greater and zero if they are equal.

Edit: here is how you can change it so that your code works:

```
Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
Date endDate = new Date(now.getTime());
endDate.SetYear(endDate.getYear() + 3);
if (cc.getExpiryDate().after(now) && cc.ExpiryDate.before(endDate)) {
 // do stuff.
}
```

You will have to take care to handle edge cases(should you include ends of the interval and so on), but this should do as approach.

Comment: Gee, and here we were trying NOT to tell him the answer ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I usually avoid telling the answer only to homeworks. This seems like a perfectly valid task one has to perform at work. If I am not experienced in some language but I need to know how to do something on it, I prefer getting an answer not a tip, because understanding the tip might take longer then coming up with a solution yourself.

Comment: Hay, no issue here, but one of the best ways to learn how to solve problems is to start with a little and see where it takes you.  JMO

Answer (score 1):

I think your entire logic is off.  You should be comparing the credit card expiry Date based on date that is `today + nYears`, not the `expiryDate + nYears`.

Take a look at `Date.after`, `Date.equals`, `Date.before`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the java doc of Date.compareTo() method...

*Returns:
the value 0 if the argument Date is equal to this Date; a value less than 0 if this Date is before the Date argument; and a value greater than 0 if this Date is after the Date argument.*

But this doesn't provide you the difference in years. It will give you only -1, 0 or 1.

**As a solution you need to extract year from date and then make a comparison.**